# MDF file is keeping deleted data

Tags: sql-server

How to get rid of deleted data (names, addresses etc) which no longer exist at database but .MDF file still has them. 
In my country there is a law obligating me to get rid of these data but I can't.
I've switched database (SQL SERVER 2005) to Simple recovery model, performed full backup and shrinked database and files (data file and log file).
The data still pesist in data file (MDF).

Comment: have a look at this question and answers on dba.stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11280/how-can-i-truly-delete-data-from-a-sql-server-table-still-shows-up-in-notepad

Comment: There is no way to force SQL Server to delete or overwrite data. You can try, but *guaranteeing* that the data is truly not there in the pages anymore is next to impossible, unless you make sure to physically overwrite all columns with data (of the exact right size!) before deleting any rows -- and even then that's subvertible. It makes far more sense to invest in solutions like [Always Encrypted](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine) instead, which will make it impossible for anyone to extract data from the file at rest.

Comment: If all you need to do is remove the data from your *current* database, without having to actively maintain the removal as an ongoing process: generate scripts for the current database, create a new one and bulk copy the existing data. This is the one method I would trust to absolutely not have any deleted data, since it literally leaves all that data behind.

Comment: Jereon, It looks like there is no other way

Answer (score 0):

Is the table a heap?

Heaps do not physically remove the data when you delete rows. To reclaim the space create a clustered index on the table.

Comment: That is not sufficient to guarantee sensitive data will not remain in a data file. A page split can leave behind data for deleted rows.